# Flutter show Progress HUD while doing background task

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I am making movie maker app where i am showing progress hud when creating movie from list of videos.But Progress HUD progress indicator UI stuck at starting point. Following is my code:

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      static List<dynamic> videosPath = List();

      static const MethodChannel methodChannel =
          const MethodChannel('moviemaker.devunion.com/movie_maker_channel');

      String _batteryLevel = 'Battery level: unknown.';
      ProgressHUD _progressHUD;
      bool _loading = false;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    //    _getBatteryLevel();

        _progressHUD = new ProgressHUD(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
          color: Colors.white,
          containerColor: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: 5.0,
          text: 'Loading...',
          loading: false,
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Widget child = new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Movie Maker'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // action button
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.movie_creation),
                onPressed: () {
                  _createMovieSync(videosPath);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: Stack(children: [_progressHUD, _buildContentSection()]),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint("Bipin - FAB pressed");
              pickVideos().asStream().listen(_setResults);
            },
            tooltip: "Pick a Video",
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );

        return child;
      }


  void toggleProgressHUD() {
    setState(() {
      if (_loading) {
        _progressHUD.state.dismiss();
      } else {
        _progressHUD.state.show();
      }
      _loading = !_loading;
    });
  }

void _createMovieSync(List<dynamic> paths) {
    toggleProgressHUD();
    _createMovie(videosPath).then((moviePath) {
      debugPrint("Bipin - _createMovieSync Movie created path: $moviePath");
      _startMovie(moviePath).then((_) {
        debugPrint("Bipin - start movie then");
      }).catchError((error) {
        debugPrint("Bipin - start movie error:");
      }).whenComplete(() {
        debugPrint("Bipin - start movie completed.");
        toggleProgressHUD();
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      debugPrint("Bipin - Create movie error: ${error.toString()}");
    }).whenComplete(() {
      debugPrint("Bipin - Create movie completed.");
    });
  }

  Future<String> _createMovie(List<dynamic> paths) {
    return Future<String>(() {
      debugPrint("Bipin - Create movie future going to sleep");
      sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
      debugPrint("Bipin - Create movie future wake up");
      return "FilePath goes here";
    });
//    return methodChannel.invokeMethod('createMovie', {"videoPaths": paths});
  }

  Future<Null> _startMovie(String moviePath) async {
    return Future<Null>(() {
      debugPrint("Bipin - Start movie future going to sleep");
      sleep(Duration(seconds: 10));
      debugPrint("Bipin - Start movie future wake up");
    });
//    debugPrint("Bipin - Created Movie path: $moviePath");
//    return methodChannel.invokeMethod('startMovie', {"moviePath": moviePath});
  }
```

Here, I am starting movie creation when a user taps on `Create Movie` action button and showing progress HUD but it is not working as expected, It's showing just like here.

[image]

Updated code to use `modal_progress_hud 0.0.6`, As suggested in answer But it's still, showing hanging progress hud. Find code here: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/MovieMaker-Flutter/commit/43b317efc9fdbc6e67cf36b16e4350587bf517ae

Answer (score 1):

I take a slightly different approach with the [modal_progress_hud](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/modal_progress_hud) package which wraps the widget you wish to make modal (with a progress indicator). After the async call returns you turn off the progress indicator. You can then play the movie.

No matter which package you use, I would probably switch to another widget to play the movie triggered by a call to setState() after making a call to stop the progress indicator. Playing the movie before the original async call completes may be preventing the progress indicator from stopping. Food for thought.

[image]

Comment: I updated my code to use `modal_progress_hud` but still showing hanging progress hud. You can find my code here: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/MovieMaker-Flutter/commit/43b317efc9fdbc6e67cf36b16e4350587bf517ae

Comment: I took a stab at getting the progress indicator to work, but ran into a similar problem as you originally described. There could be a number of reasons causing this problem (streaming the video paths, FutureBuilders getting called multiple times on rebuilds, etc... ). I recommend u review this article and linked videos which discusses options for managing state to avoid rebuilding more than is necessary, especially as app becomes more complex: https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381